# Notifying Students in Courses - Strategically

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have the following implementation, and hope to get suggestions on how to improve the code.

- `treeListViewModel.Courses` is an observablecollection
- `treeListViewModel.Courses[i].Students` is a dictionary

The code loops as follows:

```
        List<uint> DataNotificationList = new List<uint>()
        {
            2,
            6,
            9
        };

        for (int n = 0; n < DataNotificationList.Count; n++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < treeListViewModel.Courses.Count; i++)
            {
                if (treeListViewModel.Courses[i].Students.ContainsKey(DataNotificationList[n]))
                {
                    treeListViewModel.Courses[i].Students[DataNotificationList[n]].ExecuteStrategy(hasError());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: TQ monkey rolfl for correction

Comment: What do 2, 6 and 9 represent?

Comment: just indicate which to to be executed method (ExecuteStrategy)

Comment: I would add constants that specify what the ExecuteStrategy is for each of those numbers. Reading this code it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: you can go to my skydrive to have a look for my sample project and suggest for code refactoring, https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=233E2A690341BB1D!507&authkey=!AOwyW1jYlAOTSM8&ithint=file%2crar

Comment: It's best to show the code here so others can learn too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This smells of a message chain and violates the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (principle of least knowledge):

   ```
   treeListViewModel.Courses[i].Students[DataNotificationList[n]].ExecuteStrategy(hasError());
   ```

   Your caller very like doesn't care of the exact internal workings of a course - it should just dispatch the notifications and see if it succeeded. So a `Course` should probably get a method like `bool NotifyStudent(int studentId, bool hasError)`.
2. When you use expressions like `DataNotificationList[n]` in several places then it is usually better to put it in a local variable which expresses the meaning of it and also makes the code shorter, for example like this: `int studentId = DataNotificationList[n];`
3. If you don't actually need the index then `foreach` will usually suffice and is shorter.

---

So in total your refactored code could look like this:

```
    foreach (int studentId in DataNotificationList)
    {
        foreach (Course course in treeListViewModel.Courses)
        {
            if (course.NotifyStudent(studentId, hasError()))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

or if you want to go with a bit more LINQ:

```
    foreach (int studentId in DataNotificationList)
    {
        var course = treeListViewModel.Courses
                        .FirstOrDefault(c => c.NotifyStudent(studentId, hasError()));
        // could log something here and maybe raise an event handler
        // to say that a student in a course has been notified
    }
```

The `NotifyStudent` method in the course is responsible to check if the student exists in the course and return `true` once it has executed the strategy. It is totally encapsulated in the course and the caller doesn't have to know about any internals.

Comment: Hi ChrisWue, thanks for your reply ! learned and appreciate, good day !

Comment: I wouldn't use LINQ with a side-effecting method like this.

Answer (score 2):

There's not much to go on here, but I can suggest a few things.

- I don't see any benefit to using a `List` for `DataNotificationList`. A plain ol' array would work just fine. Also, I would call it `DataNotifications`. Appending the word `List` to the end smells of reverse hungarian notation to me.
- I like that you're using less than rather than `Count - 1`.

  > ```
  > for (int n = 0; n < DataNotificationList.Count; n++)
  > ```
- It's traditional to use `i`,`j`, and `k` as loop counters. Starting with `i` at the outermost level and working up the alphabet as you nest.

Comment: thank you for your reply and suggestion RubberDuck, for the DataNotifications just is a dummy data to represent receive data from external